# Using Traefik to apply a ratelimit to a subpath in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

How do I use the Traefik ingress controller to apply a ratelimit to just a subpath, while serving up the service at the root `/`?

For example I have a service called `my-webapp` and I want to serve it under `/` but ratelimit `/api/`. I tried creating an ingress with the rules:

```
- host: my-webapp.io
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: my-webapp
        servicePort: 80
      path: /api/
```

and the annotations:

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rate-limit: |
      extractorfunc: client.ip
      rateset:
        api-rateset:
          period: 1s
          average: 10
          burst: 20
```

as well as an ingress with the path `/` hoping that the more specific ingress would take priority for the `/api/` path, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Thank you for posting your thoughts, It helped me finding my issue. Actually I was using "" do define the YAML inside the YAML but as you did well you have tu use | :D

Answer (score 0):

After investigating by adding a custom response header to each ingress to determine which ingress was used, I figured out the `/api/` ingress *does* take priority. Applying ratelimits to this ingress and not the broader one appears to work, I'm not sure why it wasn't working earlier.